# DataGridView is not committing updates to database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I used the designer to set the datagridview's data source to my SQL database table. On the RowLeave event, I use the BindingSource.EndEdit to commit the changes. However, the changes in the datagridview aren't being reflected in the database. The EndEdit is being called correctly.

```
private void UI_DGV_AppData_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        entriesBindingSource.EndEdit();
        UI_DGV_AppData.Update();
        UI_DGV_AppData.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting `Update()` to update the database? That is not what that method does. [Take a look at this sample app](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid)

Comment: No that was just to ensure that the datagridview showed the updated data. I read the [BindingSource.EndEdit article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx), and it says **When the EndEdit method is called, all pending changes are applied to the underlying data source.** I thought that was all that was needed.

Comment: That just means your DataTable will have rows in the Modified state. You need to use something like a SqlDataAdapter with an UpdateCommand attached to it.

Comment: `Refresh` method is useless for update _data_. It using for _repainting_ UI control. You should remove this call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Crowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276469/crowcoder) said, `EndEdit()` won't commit the changes to the database, and you'll have to use an adapter. Right after you call `EndEdit()`, you need to call `Update()` on your table adapter. Since you used the designer, it's probably going to look something like this:

```
entriesBindingSource.EndEdit();
try
{
    DataRow row = DataSet.Entries.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
        entriesTableAdapter.Update(row);
}
```

*DataSet.Entries* will be whatever your data set and table are called. And the DGV Update/Refresh may not be needed. It's a good idea to check if the row was actually modified as well.